# Help in understanding maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

I am having trouble in understanding [link](http://rullf2.xs4all.nl/msct/node28.html) how the 5.4 has come from and the line

**" Since the distribution has to be equal to 1 at $r_u$, it must be divided by $\tilde{\phi} \exp (-d \tau K_{2}) r_u^{\nu}$"**

what does "it" mean and where from is that distribution coming? After, the distribution how is Equation (5.4) realized?
I have found no references, saying this distribution is applied in Takens formula.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It" refers to expression 5.1 which is the [cumulative distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (uppercase P). Since it is continuous and derivable, its derivative with respect to r gives you the density of probability (lowercase p).

So, in order to get 5.4 differentiate 5.1 with respect to r, and then divide by the expression given. It has to be divided by that amount so that the new truncated density of probability integrates up to 1, i.e. it is properly defined.

Comment: A) the result after taking the derivative with respect to B) they are distances, so the lower bound is zero (see explanation of equation 1). In the paper the mention that they define normalized distances to study the time series at different scales. So the variables still represent distances, but at a scale chosen according to the signal's statistical behaviour.

Comment: P.S. I have no knowledge on chaos or chaotic systems, nor can I give you a good explanation of what the paper is all about. Sorry